# Enumerable e Comparable em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Li a documentação do Ruby onde fala sobre os módulos `Enumerable` e `Comparable`, mas não entendi direito o que eles fazem. Alguém poderia me dar alguns exemplos onde utilizo eles nas minhas classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: o `Enumerable` é o responsável por buscar e ordenar e o `Comparable` por expor as regras de ordenação (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`) dos itens da enumeração.

---

A relação entre o `Enumerable` e o `Comparable` é implícita. Vamos aos conceitos:

O mixin [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html) é utilizado em coleções que precisem de métodos de busca e ordenação. A classe `Array`, do Ruby, por exemplo, estende o módulo `Enumerable`.

```
[:debito, :credito, :boleto].include? :dinheiro
=> false
```

No exemplo acima, utilizei o método [`Enumerable#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F), disponível através da classe `Array`.

Além da habilidade de busca, o `Enumerable` também ordena. O problema é: para ordenar, precisa-se de comparadores como maior, menor e igual.

Os métodos de ordenação do `Enumerable` necessitam que os itens da coleção estendam ou implementem o [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Comparable.html), ou possuam um método de nome `<=>` e retorno `1`, `0` ou `-1`.

Então é dessa forma que é possível fazer esse tipo de operação:

```
nomes = ['João', 'Maria', 'Carlos']
nomes.max
=> 'Maria'
```

Comment: Teria algum exemplo de como implemento nas minhas classes?
Aparentemente os métodos que vem no Enumerable já funcionam sem precisar dar um include.